# Behaviour of assert

Tags: c++, assembly, llvm, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to understand how assert behaves in the case of false statement. It calls __assert_fail and it calls std::abort(), according to documentation. So, I want to know what is going in assembly code of __assert_fail:

```
endbr64
pushq  %r13
movl   %edx, %r13d
movl   $0x5, %edx
pushq  %r12
movq   %rsi, %r12
leaq   0x18467e(%rip), %rsi
pushq  %rbp
movq   %rdi, %rbp
leaq   0x1804f0(%rip), %rdi       ; _libc_intl_domainname
pushq  %rbx
movq   %rcx, %rbx
subq   $0x8, %rsp
callq  0x37980                    ; __dcgettext
movq   %rbx, %r8
movl   %r13d, %ecx
movq   %r12, %rdx
movq   %rax, %rdi
movq   %rbp, %rsi
callq  0x36d70
```

What %r13 and %r12 stand for in this code? Where is the call of std::abort() and what is going on before and after this call?

Comment: `%r12` and `%r13` are two of the extra general purpose registers added by the x86-64 architecture.

Comment: Where have you obtained this disassembly from?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Those registers are set at the beginning of the function to hold a copy of the input parameters and later used to pass these values to the last call. This is pretty ordinary stuff to avoid spilling/reloading from memory. We can't tell what's going on as the code shown has zero context. Also, probably there source code is open and you can easily match it with the assembly.

Comment: @fuz I got this from special assembly debug mode in CLion.

Comment: @MargaretBloom explain please what do you mean "source code is open and you can easily match it with the assembly". About context: just program where the first line of main is the assert with false statement (assert(1==0);).

Comment: If this is a Linux system, it is probably using glibc and you can find the source code to `__assert_fail` at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/ed3ce71f5c64c5f07cbde0ef03554ea8950d8f2c/assert/assert.c#L98.  The entire glibc is open source.  Note the `_(...)` macro which expands to a call to some version of the `gettext` function, to return a pre-written translation of the message; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext.

Comment: Correlating your disassembly with this source code, the `callq  0x36d70` at the end is presumably calling `__assert_fail_base`, defined above in the same file.  It is that function which calls `abort`, and so that's why you don't see a call to `abort` within `__assert_fail` itself.

Comment: Wait, isn't `__assert_fail` `noreturn`? Maybe the confusion here is because the compiler is saving things that will never get restored.